# Help to understand the relationship between Sylow Theorem and Direct Products or Isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking at a solution to this problem: Prove every group of order $14077=6 \cdot 2011$ is cyclic using Sylow Theorems.

Basically, here is an outline of the proof... I know we firstly want to use the fact that $n_{2011}$ and $n_{7}$ are equal to $1$, which I understand as it follows directly from Sylow's theorems and doing the math required to fulfill the theorems. Then, if we call each of those unique Sylow subgroups $Q$ and $P$ (for the $7$ and then $2011$ ones respectively), then we note that each is normal in $G$ since each is unique. Then we deduce that of course $PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$...

...and then I need some help. I see that $P \cap Q = 1$ because $P$ and $Q$ only have the identity in common...?  But I'm not sure I understand why this is.

After I understand that part, I can use $|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P \cap Q|}$ from previous theorems, and see that $|PQ|=\frac{2011 \cdot 7}{1}=|G|$ and so $G=PQ$. That makes sense.

BUT...most importantly, please, I need to understand the next part because the idea has shown up in several problems, but I don't know where it all comes from:

Since $P,Q \trianglelefteq G$ and $P \cap Q = 1$, then $PQ \cong P \text{ x } Q$ (what?  I don't see any theorem like this in my textbook...how do we know this?) Finally, since $|P|$ and $|Q|$ are both prime, $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2011}$ and $Q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. So, $G=PQ \cong P \text{ x } Q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2011} \text{ x } \mathbb{Z}_{7} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{14077}$.  I don't fully understand any of this last part with all the isomorphisms (I understand the arithmetic of it, but not really "how" we know to do this...and how do we know that $PQ \cong P \text{ x } Q?$). Finally, how exactly does it follow from all this that $Z_{14077}$ is cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

**Proof that $|P \cap Q| = 1$.**

$P \cap Q $ is a subgroup of both $P$ and $Q$. By Lagrange's theorem, its order divides both $|P|$ and $|Q|$ and therefore is $1$.

**Proof that if $P,Q⊴G$ and $P∩Q=1$ then $pq=qp$ for every $p$ in $P$ and $q$ in $Q$.**

Consider $p^{-1}q^{-1}pq$. This element is in both $P$ and $Q$ (can you see why?) It is therefore the identity and so $pq=qp$.

**Proof that the direct product of two cyclic groups of coprime order is itself cyclic.**

Consider the product of a generator of $P$ with a generator of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you S. Dolan, between what you said, and I also realized there was an entire chapter regarding direct products after the chapter on Sylow Theorems in my textbook, I found out the answers to many of my questions. They are mostly basic theorems and properties. Thanks for explaining the intersection of P and Q being 1, though. And, to answer your "can you see why?" question, no i dont see why that commutator element (?) is equal to the identity. We don't know that the group is abelian, do we? And, what's the relevance of that part anyway at this point?

Comment: $p^{−1}q^{−1}p$ is in $Q$ since $Q⊴G$. So the commutator is in $Q$. Similarly, it is in $P$ and so must be the identity.